# X2GO: Clipboard (copy/paste) stops working from Windows 10 to Linux CentOS and vice-versa

Tags: x2go

I'm using X2GO to connect to a remote VM from my Windows 10 OS, but clipboard breaks after I try to copy/paste something from my local machine to the remote. It initially works after I start the session, but it stops working after few times of copy/paste.

The things is that when it happens, Windows clipboard stops functioning also.

Only after I restart the session, clipboard works again until it breaks.

There is no much on this issue in the internet. I tried few options suggested by some people, but it didn't help.

The remote machine is CentOS 7.7.1908.

I'm using latest X2GO Client/Server:

Client v. 4.1.2.2

Server v. 3.5.99.25

Any suggestion for workaround?

Answer (score 22):

Just after I published my question, I was hit by "eureka" discovery and found the solution.

Follow these steps:

- Open X2GO Client application
- Click "Options" menu --> Settings
- Select "X. Org Server Settings" tab
- Select "do not use primary clipboard" (make sure its CHECKED!)
- Click OK
- **!!! RESTART X2GO CLIENT !!!**

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, sometimes clipboard breaks even with these settings:

> Click "Options" menu --> Settings
> Select "X. Org Server Settings" tab
> Select "do not use primary clipboard" (make sure its CHECKED!)

I use following workaround when this happened. I copy any text on the remote machine and than copy on my local. After that, clipboard is fine (not for long)

Comment: yes, even with these settings it happens, but rarely. in my case, its stable enough. I suggest to restart the session if it happens to you

Comment: IMHO those changes do not really make a difference. It works... Until a certain moment. Then it is broken.
Then I suspend the session and resume again and it is okay again.

Comment: The "copy from remote to local" trick usually fixes copying from local to remote for me. I just have to randomly copy in both directions to keep it working. No amount of restarting x2go fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Running x2goclient inside [wsl2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps) should solve this problem.

It looks like this if running inside wsl2:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the remote server within X2go I opened up an editor and tried copying and pasting in there to 'reset' things and then it worked in the terminal again

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).